# Finding value of a function at limit zero

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I want to evaluate the below function at limit zero. I tried with a function which has double differentiation for which it is giving me a finite value. For triple differentiation it is consistently giving output as zero. I want to know if the function given below can be evaluated and if not what could be the reason.

```
RF[r_] := (1/r)0.200731 (-0.000343151 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 0.137662 r] - 
   0.0642014 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 0.205217 r] + 
   0.116823 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 0.269851 r] - 
   0.188628 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 0.333395 r] + 
   0.174251 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 0.3964 r] + 
   0.0371598 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 0.459094 r] - 
   0.124404 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 0.521592 r] - 
   0.0878417 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 0.583959 r] + 
   0.0341412 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 0.646234 r] + 
   0.110696 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 0.70844 r] + 
   0.0979234 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 0.770594 r] + 
   0.0284896 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 0.832709 r] - 
   0.048473 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 0.894793 r] - 
   0.0981621 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 0.956851 r] - 
   0.11019 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 1.01889 r] - 
   0.0901751 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 1.08091 r] - 
   0.0513123 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 1.14292 r] - 
   0.00632141 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 1.20491 r] + 
   0.0352401 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 1.26689 r] + 
   0.0682566 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 1.32887 r] + 
   0.0908501 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 1.39084 r] + 
   0.103587 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 1.4528 r] + 
   0.108074 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 1.51475 r] + 
   0.106441 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 1.5767 r] + 
   0.100633 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 1.63865 r] + 
   0.0923663 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 1.70059 r] + 
   0.0828932 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 1.76253 r] + 
   0.0731573 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 1.82446 r] + 
   0.0637315 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 1.88639 r] + 
   0.0549955 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 1.94832 r] + 
   0.04711 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 2.01025 r] + 
   0.0401549 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 2.07217 r] + 
   0.0340995 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 2.13409 r] + 
   0.0288995 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 2.19601 r] + 
   0.02446 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 2.25793 r] + 
   0.0207028 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 2.31985 r] + 
   0.0175275 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 2.38176 r] + 
   0.0148598 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 2.44368 r] + 
   0.0126148 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 2.50559 r] + 
   0.0107338 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 2.5675 r] + 
   0.0091515 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 2.62941 r] + 
   0.0078254 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 2.69132 r] + 
   0.00670751 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 2.75323 r] + 
   0.00576856 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 2.81514 r] + 
   0.00497396 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 2.87705 r] + 
   0.00430427 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 2.93895 r] + 
   0.00373467 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 3.00086 r] + 
   0.00325262 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 3.06276 r] + 
   0.00284023 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 3.12467 r] + 
   0.00248963 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 3.18657 r] + 
   0.00218777 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 3.24848 r] + 
   0.00192993 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 3.31038 r] + 
   0.00170643 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 3.37228 r] + 
   0.00151461 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 3.43418 r] + 
   0.00134719 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 3.49608 r] + 
   0.00120281 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 3.55798 r] + 
   0.0010759 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 3.61989 r] + 
   0.000965963 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 3.68179 r] + 
   0.000868629 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 3.74369 r] + 
   0.000783953 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 3.80558 r] + 
   0.000708442 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 3.86748 r] + 
   0.000642491 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 3.92938 r] + 
   0.000583255 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 3.99128 r] + 
   0.000531332 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 4.05318 r] + 
   0.000484364 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 4.11508 r] + 
   0.000443062 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 4.17698 r] + 
   0.000405441 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 4.23887 r] + 
   0.000372266 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 4.30077 r] + 
   0.000341841 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 4.36267 r] + 
   0.000314949 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 4.42456 r] + 
   0.00029012 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 4.48646 r] + 
   0.000268132 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 4.54836 r] + 
   0.0002477 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 4.61025 r] + 
   0.000229577 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 4.67215 r] + 
   0.00021263 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 4.73405 r] + 
   0.000197583 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 4.79594 r] + 
   0.000183424 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 4.85784 r] + 
   0.000170843 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 4.91973 r] + 
   0.000158933 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 4.98163 r] + 
   0.000148347 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 5.04352 r] + 
   0.000138266 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 5.10542 r] + 
   0.000129305 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 5.16731 r] + 
   0.00012072 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 5.22921 r] + 
   0.000113092 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 5.2911 r] + 
   0.000105741 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 5.353 r] + 
   0.0000992116 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 5.41489 r] + 
   0.0000928812 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 5.47678 r] + 
   0.0000872617 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 5.53868 r] + 
   0.0000817795 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 5.60057 r] + 
   0.0000769142 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 5.66247 r] + 
   0.0000721356 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 5.72436 r] + 
   0.0000678925 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 5.78625 r] + 
   0.0000636919 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 5.84815 r] + 
   0.0000599513 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 5.91004 r] + 
   0.0000562072 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 5.97193 r] + 
   0.000052841 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 6.03383 r] + 
   0.0000494044 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 6.09572 r] + 
   0.0000462225 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 6.15761 r] + 
   0.0000428304 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 6.21951 r] + 
   0.0000395045 r SphericalBesselJ[3, 6.2814 r])
```

This is a wavefunction which includes spherical bessel functions

```
urF[r] := Abs[D[D[D[RF[r], r], r], r]]^2
```

I want to differentiate it three times and then evaluate at limit zero

```
DRF = Limit[urF[r], r -> 0, GenerateConditions -> False]
```

I am trying to evaluate the function at limit zero but it is giving me output as 0. I want a value even if it is very small. I tried using

`$MinPrecision = 20;`
`$MaxPrecision = 30;`

But it is still not working. Any suggestions on how to overcome this.
Thank you in advance

Comment: what happens if you change `urF[r] :=...` to `urF[r_] :=...` and change `urF8[r]` to `urF[r]` as there is no  `urF8[r]`  anywhere in your code.

Comment: And you do not have to write `D[D[D[RF[r], r], r], r]` you can just write `D[RF[r],{r,3}]`

Comment: Yeah its ```urF[r]``` only. I will correct it in the original question. I was trying to see if it is differentiable that is why i wrote it like ```D[D[D[RF[r], r], r], r]```.

Comment: if you remove `Abs` I get `0.0111299` as limit.  Why did you add `Abs` ?

Comment: I wanted the function to have a positive value. I will check it once without absolute and see if it works for all of my other function and let you know. Thank you for your help good sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After sometime, it does give answer with `Abs` also.

using V 14 on windows:

```
RF[r_] := (* see original post*)
urF[r_] := Abs[D[RF[r], {r, 3}]]^2
Limit[urF[r], r -> 0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]